# How to shift the application of a function down a row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

If I have a dataframe or list of dataframes that I am applying a function to such as:

```
df1
start stop ID
0     10   x
10    20   y
20    30   z

df2
start stop ID
0     10   a
10    20   b
20    30   c
```

Lets say I use the function:

```
mylist=list(df1,df2)
mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) {x$Avg<-(((x[,1]+x[,2]))/2) ; return(x)})
```

Which gives me the output:

```
df1
start stop ID Avg
0     10   x  5
10    20   y  15
20    30   z  25

df2
start stop ID Avg
0     10   a  5
10    20   b  15
20    30   c  25
```

But I want it to display the average of the row below such that the output would be this (I don't care what goes in the non-computable row):

```
df1
start stop ID Avg
0     10   x  15
10    20   y  25
20    30   z  NA

df2
start stop ID Avg
0     10   a  15
10    20   b  25
20    30   c  NA
```

How do I do this? And it needs to be in lapply because I will be doing it to several dozen dataframes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the first element (`[-1]`) from the output and concatenate with NA.  In case you have NA values, it may be useful to do `rowMeans` on the first two columns as it has an option to remove the NA values (`na.rm=TRUE`).

```
 lapply(mylist, function(x) { x$Avg <-c(rowMeans(x[-3])[-1],NA)
                             x})
 #[[1]]
 #  start stop ID Avg
 #1     0   10  x  15
 #2    10   20  y  25
 #3    20   30  z  NA

 #[[2]]
 #  start stop ID Avg
 #1     0   10  a  15
 #2    10   20  b  25
 #3    20   30  c  NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun. This took care of it